# How to return multiple Promises within an array in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, promise, sequelize.js

I'm currently trying to run multiple queries within Sequelize and return an array of promises back to where the function was called. How do I return the array with the promises back to the function as a promise so that it can be resolved later on?

Function calling the query:

```
router.get('/barchart', (req, res) => {
  store.getBarchartData().then(session => {
    res.json(session);
  })
})
```

Query function:

```
getBarchartData(data) {
    let promises = [];
    let curr = new Date();
    let start = startOfWeek(curr);
    let date = start.getDate();
    let month = start.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = start.getFullYear();
    let startDateString = year + "-" + month + "-" + date;
    let queryDate;



     for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          startDateString = addDays(startDateString, 1);
          queryDate = format(startDateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
          promises.push(models.session.findAll({
            where: { date: { [Op.eq]: queryDate }  },
            attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('id')), 'y']]
          }))
        }
        console.log(promises);
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }
```

When the query is run it returns an array of promises seen below which I want to return back to the other function:

```
[ Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined } ]
```

Comment: you can return array of promises instead of Promise.all(promises) in query function, then you can easily resolve all these promises later in your function calling the query.

Comment: @VikashDahiya I returned the array of promises and then resolved  in the function. Worked a charm thank you